# static broadcast gives error

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have a broadcast receiver and im again broadcasting message from that broadcast onreceive's method .

```
public static class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent1 = new Intent("com.test.test");
        sendBroadcast(intent1); 
    }
}
```

But it gives error on sendBroadcast

```
cannot make a static reference to the non-static method sendbroadcast(intent) 
from the type context wrapper.
```

please help me solving this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
    context.sendBroadcast(intent1);
```

instead of

```
    sendBroadcast(intent1);
```

because `sendBroadcast` is not method of `BroadcastReceiver` class.

Comment: I have already done that, but you give the right answer.can you tell me why context is necessary before sendbrodcast.?. sendBroadcast belong to which class?

Comment: @wqrahd : from [ContextWrapper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html) class

Comment: why context is needed if class become static.?

Comment: @wqrahd : `cannot make a static reference to the non-static method sendbroadcast(intent) 
from the type context wrapper.` means you are trying to access non in non static way. as you if we want to access methods from any class we need to use class object

Answer (score -1):

you are using wrong syntax for making broadcast receiver
first you need to understand what is meaning of static class in java?
[Static Class](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-class-in-java/)

and now you must refer these link for implementation of broadcast receiver
[Link 1](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html)